# Conversion of UIWebview into UIImage

Tags: uiwebview

I am trying to convert UIWebview into UIImage in WebviewDidFinishLoading method.But it doest not rendering the complete html.

How to know UIwebview is fully loaded or rendering is completed in iOS without using private API's?